# If an app stores file on sdcard, can a user access them?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I just need a confirmation. If my app saves data to the phone's sdcard (`/sdcard/com.example.myapp/file.mp3`), can a user browse to such folder on the card and mess with the files (delete, rename, etc.)? I cannot find such info on the developer's site.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes he can, there is no problem whatsoever. He will be able to see the files and modify them via the built in file manager, via code or from the PC when the device is connected.

Comment: Hmm I thought he/she could do that. So then why do I see so many developers suggest we store apps external files on such locations? Isn't it better to user remote servers? For the sake of security and stability of the app (guess a user deleted files needed for the app that's based on playing sound files).

Comment: @askmo. It all depends on what files you think of. I would e.g. like to be able to use the application even if the server is down. So it's more stable if you have the files on the sdcard, but it might be less secure. It's also faster to load data from sdcard instead of servers.

Comment: @Federico. My app fetches a sound file on user's click. You think it would be better to save those files on sdcard? Or both? When you develop such apps, aren't you worried about limits of a sdcard?

Comment: You can use the code in this link http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1271/ to know if there is available space in the sdcard. If it is, you save it and if it's not, you tell the user that he can buy a bigger one :).

Comment: @askmo My application stores the files on the sdcard and uses them, but reverts back to a few default files that I have in the application if the sdcard is unavailable. Trying to get a sound file from a remote server when a user clicks is probably way too slow.

Comment: You're probably right thou many droid users use wi-fi so catching remote files is not such a problem. of course, if these are smaller files.

Comment: In Latinamerica for example it ain't so easy to find a Wi-Fi Hotspot. There are allot, but it is not exactly popular, nor unlimited data plans.

Answer (score 2):

Yes he can modify the files on the sdcard. You can verify it by e.g installing Astro and browse the sdcard, and modify files on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

The SD card is *capable* of storing files with crypto protection called [CPRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Protection_for_Recordable_Media). Most devices that use SD cards don't bother to support it. Mere mortals such as ourselves cannot obtain keys to use the CPRM features on the card.

Comment: LOL so why mentioning it?! :))))